# How to create framework with resources in it for iOS using Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am trying to create framework for my iOS projects but I cant get right procedure for it. I followed some procedures and created framework but unable to use it in my project. 
 i followed following links
http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/

Comment: Try this: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed following links:
[http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725152740/http://locomoviles.com:80/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/)

[http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725152740/http://locomoviles.com:80/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/)

also this helped me a lot

[http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios](https://www.raywenderlich.com/2430-how-to-create-a-framework-for-ios)